# Is there a keyboard shortcut to reach the width field in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Is there a keyboard shortcut to focus the width field in the Inkscape toolbar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK there is no existing shortcut to directly put input focus into the width field on the controls bar of the select tool. It can however be done with these commands:

1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to move focus to first entry on the controls bar,
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move focus from the `X:` to the `W:` field

The steps above refer to the controls bar of the select tool (<kbd>F1</kbd>). In general, the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> works in several tool contexts to move focus to the first input on the tool's controls bar (e.g. rectangle, ellipse/circle, spiral tool, spray tool, tweak tool, text tool).

Comment: JFTR - Inkscape's keyboard and mouse reference > [Tool controls bar](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/keys092.html#d0e610)